# Do images/videos in Media Library have unique ID? And how to get it?

Tags: ios, swift

My App requirement is let user multiple select a bunch of images or videos on device's library, then edit (captions, effects ...) and upload to server. So i think when user select items from library, i will save selected items's id to a list, and when uploading i will check if file still existed (by id), if all OK, the file will be uploaded.

My question is, does items in media library (iOS) has unique ID ? If YES, how to get it ?

By the way, i think i would use below library for selecting items in library:
https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm not trying but you can try with the PHObject's `localIdentifier`. Reference here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phobject

Comment: Yes. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phobject/1622400-localidentifier

Comment: How you are fetching the images/videos from media library? Share you code please. Note: PHObject's localIdentifier will help you surely.